# Filling a buffer with emptiness

Tags: node.js, buffer

How can I fill a buffer with emptiness?

This was working on v0.10.*:

```
var b = new Buffer(8192);
b.fill("");
```

But it just crashes without any error on `v0.11.11`.

I have this code:

```
var b = new Buffer(8192);
b.fill("");

console.log(1);
```

When I run it, `1` doesn't appear in output. What alternatives are to fill a buffer with emptiness?

Comment: Did you try `new Buffer(Array(32))`?

Comment: @remus It seems that `b.fill(0)` works fine. But I need an elegant solution.

Comment: @remus Can you confirm this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227510/205508

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a . instead of ? at first.

Comment: @remus Then, post an answer there. Thanks!

Comment: @remus I meant on meta. :p I will vote this up too, but I will not accept it yet. Waiting more solutions. If you are the best I will mark your answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally I suggested `new Buffer(Array(32))`, but we determined `b.fill(0)` was a workable solution.